# What is the meaning of the following commands when installing Skype

Tags: linux, installation, fedora

Today, I follow this tutorial [Skype Installation](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/install-skype-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel-scientific-linux-sl/) in order to install Skype on Fedora 16. In the instruction, the author says that:

```
touch /usr/bin/skype
chmod 755 /usr/bin/skype

Open /usr/bin/skype with text editor and add following content:
#!/bin/sh
export SKYPE_HOME="/opt/skype"
```

I don't understand the way touch and chmod 755 work together? Not only in this tutorial but some other tutorials I came up with, I also see these two commands go together when installing programs in Linux.

Moreover, I don't know what this line means

```
export SKYPE_HOME="/opt/skype"
```

Please explain to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note: the `/usr/bin/skype` shell script you are creating also needs a command to actually start the skype application. The recipe at http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/install-skype-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel-scientific-linux-sl/ also includes this line `$SKYPE_HOME/skype --resources=$SKYPE_HOME $*`

Comment: @BrianSwift thank you, but only above commands make me confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `touch /usr/bin/skype`

This command will create the file `/usr/bin/skype` if it does not already exist. [Read more about `touch`.](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/touch/)

> `chmod 755 /usr/bin/skype`

This command will change the *mode* of `/usr/bin/skype`. [Read more about `chmod`.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)

- 7 means the file owner can read, write, and execute the file.
- 5 means members of the group that owns the file can read and execute the file.
- The last 5 means anyone on the computer can read and execute the file.

> `export SKYPE_HOME="/opt/skype"`

This command will create an environment variable named `SKYPE_HOME`. [Read more about `export`.](http://ss64.com/bash/export.html)

Answer (score 1):

> touch

creates an new file with current date/time.

> chmod 755

allow owner to read/write/execute file, everyone else - to read and execute (no write).

> export SKYPE_HOME="/opt/skype"

creates an Environemental Variable called SKYPE_HOME for Skype's internal use.

Comment: `touch` creates files, or updates an existing files time/date. It won't work for a directory that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Rob it's a file sorry

Comment: chmod 755 in this context means allow owner to read/write/execute file, everyone else - to read and execute (no write)